# how to correctly set environment setting for more than one projects in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, environment-variables, settings

I have a project called "myplanet" and my `manage.py‍` file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myplanet.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I know that I have to set a system variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE:myplanet.settings`  and also set the `PYTHONPATH` to my `settings.py` file. I was wondering what I should do in the case of another project that is called gMaps ? I tried to do the same but it does not simply work. My OS is Windows 7 x64

Comment: What's the relationship between the two projects?

Comment: There is no relationship

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear here!

Comment: well, I have 2 Django project in my computer. When I set enviroment variables for one project I cannot run the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up two independent virtual environments for each project. It's best practice I think. In that case you can even install different versions of python packages for each project as it required.

You can read about using virtualenv and it's wrapper here: 
http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set `PYTHONPATH` variable environment to your django project for running that, when your `settings.py` is inside a package or is a module that is importable with `manage.py`.

The [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is a list of directories Python goes through to search for modules and files.

If you need to add a path of one library or your root path of project to it, you can do that in your code.

For example in `manage.py` with:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/my/project")
```

Or:

```
import os
BASE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(BASE_PATH + '/src/folder/of/my/project/')
```

And each django project has own `manage.py‍` file that set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` enivoronment itself, and you don't need to set that.

I think if your `manage.py` have this line:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myplanet.settings")
```

Then, you just need to have this structure for your project:

```
myplanet # It's a project folder
  myplanet # It's a package
    __init__.py
    settings.py
  manage.py
```

And you can run your project with `python manage.py runserver` without set `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.